# Construction of cosmological models using group actions over a manifold

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, symmetry, group-theory

I am searching for good resources on topics related to construction of symmetries over a manifold. For example in Schwarzschild model when looking for spherical symmetry, in cosmology when applying homogeneity or isotropy.  All types of symmetries are applied using Lie group actions on manifold but it seems that nowhere this operations were made rigorous. Really looking forward to recommendations of books and papers that contains these steps in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Some good books on the topic are John K. Beem, Paul Ehrlich and Kevin Easley's Global Lorentzian Geometry (it has a nice section on cosmology and its relation to homogeneity and isotropy), Stephani's Exact Solutions of Einstein's Field Equations (a few chapters on group actions on spacetimes as well as some proofs for various spacetimes of various degrees of symmetries), and Wolf's Spaces of constant curvature for more mathematical details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I will check them now and inform you as soon as possible.

Comment: I think these resources are what I needed but if I get some help on the "big" picture, I would be grateful. So I have experience with homogeneous spaces, Riemann homogeneous spaces and I have seen example of applying symmetries in Schwarzschild metric (spherical symm. - SO(3) as a group of isomeries on orbits and etc.). But in some materials including yours the Killing vector fields are the main tool. I know that they are Lie algebra of group of isometries but I dont know which method is formal. So could you please explain the process step by step with references in the books? Thank you!